# EF & listview to display value from lookup table

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, data-binding

I have 2 tables:

User(Id PK, TitleId FK, Name, Active)

Title(Id PK, Text)

Table Title is a lookup table of titles (Mr, Miss,...) and its got a relationship with table User by TitleId.

Now I'm trying to display the data in a web page using .net and Entity Framework. I'm using a ListView control and a query as a source. it all displays fine except for the Title.

Here is my code:

```
    MyEntities _entities = new MyEntities ();

    User user = new User(_entities);
    IQueryable u = (from x in _entities.Users
           where x.Active == true
           select x);

    ListView1.DataSource = u;
    ListView1.DataBind();
```

and the code in the front end:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" DataKeyNames="Id">

<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%# Eval("Id") %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%# Eval("Title.Text") %>
        </td>

        <td>
            <%# Eval("Name") %>
        </td>
     </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<LayoutTemplate>
                 <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <th id="Th2" runat="server">
                            Id</th>
                        <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                            Title</th>
                        <th id="Th3" runat="server">
                            Name</th>
                        <th runat="server">
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder">
                    </tr>
                </table>

</LayoutTemplate>
```

How do I manage to get the Title Text associated with a User to display on the ListView?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with LINQ. Does LINQ figure out the FKs for you and automatically create the JOINS for you?

Comment: yeah it allows me to access the value "User.Title.Text" but it comes blank in the front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to do it:

_entities.Users.Include("Title")